# Fetch the Doc lib object by passing the Internal Name of Doc Lib [ NOT Display Name]

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, ssom, internal-name

I want to fetch the document library object  by passing the `internalname` of the `doc lib`.
is it possible?
like

```
 splist mydoclib = ospweb.lists.trygetlist("INTERNALNAME_OF_DOCLIB");
```

usually we pass the `title/display name` of the `doc lib` / `list` to  fetch the  object, but in my case there is a chance that,  my customer my change the display name by modifying the doc lib title in future. i would like to avoid this in my code, such that i dont hardcode the doc lib name [display name] in my C# code. am using `SSOM`

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I've figures for how to do this is to read all SPLists into an enumerable, then use a little LINQ magic to get the list you want based on InternalName using the [SPList RootFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.rootfolder.aspx).Name property. I have not tested the impact of reading all web lists into memory may have, but a basic example is below....

```
List<SPList> lists = oWeb.Lists.Cast<SPList>().ToList();
SPList oList = lists.First(o => o.RootFolder.Name == "YourListInternalName");
```

Comment: I will test this and revert here. Thanks for your time.